# How can I exclude multiple values from an operation? Would I use an or operator along with an if else statement?

Tags: c#, if-statement, random, dice, or-operator

I know it would be easier if I just use consecutive numbers, but I want to make it easier for the user to select a number that corresponds to the die type they pick. If I use an or operator am I limited to comparing just two things? This is what I tried to do but it didn't work. Is my syntax wrong or can I not string multiple terms in one statement?:

```
if (typeOfDice != 4 || typeOfDice != 6 || 
        typeOfDice != 8 || typeOfDice != //10 || typeOfDice != 12 || 
        typeOfDice != 20 || typeOfDice != 100)
```

> Here is the short program I'm trying to make it work in. I just want to make sure the user can't break the program:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Start:
        Random roll = new Random();

        // Request dice type from user
        Console.WriteLine("Please input the type of dice you want to roll. ");

        // Display dice types to user
        Console.WriteLine("4) Four-sided");
        Console.WriteLine("6) Six-sided");
        Console.WriteLine("8) Eight-sided");
        Console.WriteLine("10) Ten-sided");
        Console.WriteLine("12) Twelve-sided");
        Console.WriteLine("20) Twenty-sided");
        Console.WriteLine("100) Percentage");
        Console.WriteLine(" ");

        // Take dice type from user
        Console.Write("Type of Dice: ");
        int typeOfDice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine(" ");

        // Prevents user from breaking the program by printing a corrective message
        // and restarting the program in the event an inappropriate choice is made by the user.
        if (typeOfDice != 4 || typeOfDice != 6 ||
        typeOfDice != 8 || typeOfDice != //10 || typeOfDice != 12 || 
        typeOfDice != 20 || typeOfDice != 100)
            Console.WriteLine("That is not an acceptable die type. Please try again.");
        goto Start;
        else
        {

            // Initiates random variable and total variable
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int total = 0;

            // Request number of dice from user
            Console.WriteLine("Please input the number of dice you want to roll ");
            Console.WriteLine(" ");

            // Accept number of dice from user 
            Console.Write("Number of Dice: ");
            int numberOfDice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine(" ");

            /// Assigns random generator parameters to user's choice of dice type and 
            // generates random number, looping until the die is rolled the requested 
            // number of times and the result of each new roll is added to the total
            switch (typeOfDice)
            {

                case 4:
                    for (int count = 0; count < numberOfDice; count++)
                    {

                        int currentRoll = rnd.Next(typeOfDice);
                        total += currentRoll + 1;
                        Console.Write("{0} ", currentRoll + 1);
                        //Console.WriteLine(" ");

                    }
                    break;

                case 6:
                    for (int count = 0; count < numberOfDice; count++)
                    {

                        int currentRoll = rnd.Next(typeOfDice);
                        total += currentRoll + 1;
                        Console.Write("{0} ", currentRoll + 1);
                        //Console.WriteLine(" ");

                    }
                    break;

                case 8:
                    for (int count = 0; count < numberOfDice; count++)
                    {

                        int currentRoll = rnd.Next(typeOfDice);
                        total += currentRoll + 1;
                        Console.Write("{0} ", currentRoll + 1);
                        //Console.WriteLine(" ");

                    }
                    break;

                case 10:
                    for (int count = 0; count < numberOfDice; count++)
                    {

                        int currentRoll = rnd.Next(typeOfDice);
                        total += currentRoll + 1;
                        Console.Write("{0} ", currentRoll + 1);
                        //Console.WriteLine(" ");

                    }
                    break;

                case 12:
                    for (int count = 0; count < numberOfDice; count++)
                    {

                        int currentRoll = rnd.Next(typeOfDice);
                        total += currentRoll + 1;
                        Console.Write("{0} ", currentRoll + 1);
                        //Console.WriteLine(" ");

                    }
                    break;

                case 20:
                    for (int count = 0; count < numberOfDice; count++)
                    {

                        int currentRoll = rnd.Next(typeOfDice);
                        total += currentRoll + 1;
                        Console.Write("{0} ", currentRoll + 1);
                        // Console.WriteLine(" ");

                    }
                    break;

                case 100:
                    for (int count = 0; count < numberOfDice; count++)
                    {

                        int currentRoll = rnd.Next(typeOfDice);
                        total += currentRoll + 1;
                        Console.Write("{0} ", currentRoll + 1);
                        //Console.WriteLine(" ");

                    }
                    break;

            }

            // Prints total of dice rolls.
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            Console.WriteLine("Total: {0}", total);
            Console.WriteLine(" ");

            goto Start;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Did you mean to comment out part of the comparison? `typeOfDice != //10 ...` That line will probably not compile as-is.

Answer (score 1):

You want an && (Logical AND) between your test not an || (Logical OR)

```
if (typeOfDice != 4 && 
    typeOfDice != 6 && 
    typeOfDice != 8 && 
    typeOfDice != 10 && 
    typeOfDice != 12 && 
    typeOfDice != 20 && 
    typeOfDice != 100)
```

With the `|| operator`, also if you select a correct value for the dice, the if evaluation is always true.
For example, suppose that your user select a dice=4, now this dice value (4) is different than the dice value 6 (or other acceptable value) and thus your condition will always find a condition that is true and your code prints the error message

Also I wish to introduce you to the enum keyword.

```
public enum DiceType
{
   FourSides = 4,
   SixSides= 6,
   EightSides = 8,
   TenSides = 10,
   TwelveSides = 12,
   TwentySides = 20,
   Percentage = 100
}
```

Now instead of using magic numbers you use a variable of this enum type

```
Random roll = new Random();
while(true)
{
    // Request dice type from user
    Console.WriteLine("Please input the type of dice you want to roll. ");

    // Display dice types to user
    Console.WriteLine("4) Four-sided");
    Console.WriteLine("6) Six-sided");
    Console.WriteLine("8) Eight-sided");
    Console.WriteLine("10) Ten-sided");
    Console.WriteLine("12) Twelve-sided");
    Console.WriteLine("20) Twenty-sided");
    Console.WriteLine("100) Percentage");
    Console.WriteLine(" ");
    Console.WriteLine("Type quit to exit ");

    // Take dice type from user
    Console.Write("Type of Dice: ");
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    if(input == "quit")
       break;

    DiceType typeOfDice;

    // Try to parse the input and check if it could be an enum of the 
    // desidered type (Note user can also input "foursides" not just 4
    if (!Enum.TryParse<DiceType>(input, true, out typeOfDice) || 
        !Enum.IsDefined(typeof(DiceType), typeOfDice))
        Console.WriteLine("That is not an acceptable die type. Please try again.");
    else
    {
       ....
       switch (typeOfDice)
       {
           case DiceType.FourSides:
               .....
               break;
           case DiceType.SixSides:
               .....
               break;

           ....
        }
    }
}
```

I have also removed the goto code. Instead of this famous bad practice I have added an infinite loop around the code. A new choice in your menu (quit) allows your user to exit the loop and terminate the program

Comment: That seems to have fixed, it, thanks. But I am getting an error now for the goto Start; statement right before the else statement. It wants a curly bracket, but I thought I could just have a semi colon there and it would take it back to the start label at the top. At the end of the program I also have a goto Start; statement that seems to work fine. Adding curly brackets doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Do not use goto. It is really a bad practice and can be the source of very difficult to spot bugs. Instead enclose all the code that need to be repeated inside an infinite loop  _while(true)_, add a new choice to your menu ("Type quit to exit"), check for this word before entering the parse of the DiceType code and add a _break_ statement to exit from the infinite loop